# How can I merge multiple Excel files with multiple sheets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-development-mode

Can anyone please help me to write code if sheet names are matching in several files then data will merge and create one data frame. I want to merge multiple file in one dictionary.

I am getting this error:

```
> AttributeError  
Traceback (most recent call last)  
Cell In[78], line 8  
      6 path = os.path.join(root, fname)  
      7 print(path)  
----> 8 for sheet_name in path.sheet_names():   
      9     print(sheet_name)  
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sheet_names'
```

Code

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
# Load the Excel file
#xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(excel_filepath)
# Use additional arguments to read the sheets
df_dict_flex = {}
for root, dirs,files in os.walk('path'):
    for fname in files:
        xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(os.path.join(root, fname))
        print(xls_file)
        # Checking sheet names in every excel file
        for sheet_name in xls_file.sheet_names:
                if sheet_name != 'Portfolios' and sheet_name != 'SP Search Term Report':
                    df_dict_flex[sheet_name] = file.parse(sheet_name,)
df_dict_flex
```

Comment: Here is a related question, but for multiple files with only one sheet each: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74646115/merge-all-excel-files-into-one-file-with-multiple-sheets Maybe the answer will still be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# Define the path where the Excel files are located
path = 'your/excel/files/path'

# Initialize a dictionary to store DataFrames
df_dict_flex = {}

# Walk through the directory containing the Excel files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for fname in files:
        # Construct the full file path
        file_path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        # Ensure that you're only processing Excel files
        if file_path.endswith('.xlsx') or file_path.endswith('.xls'):
            # Load the Excel file
            xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
            print(xls_file)  # This should print the ExcelFile object, not a string

            # Extract sheet names in every Excel file
            for sheet_name in xls_file.sheet_names:
                print(sheet_name)  # This should print each sheet name

                # Check if the sheet name matches the given condition
                if sheet_name == 'Portfolios' or sheet_name == 'SP Search Term Req':
                    # Parse the specific sheet into a DataFrame
                    df = xls_file.parse(sheet_name)
                    # Store the DataFrame in the dictionary
                    df_dict_flex[sheet_name] = df

# The df_dict_flex dictionary now contains DataFrames for each sheet that matches the conditions
#Make sure to replace 'your/excel/files/path' with the actual path to your Excel files. may this helps to you
```

Comment: may this helps to you

Comment: I can see only first file data through this script.